# Creating a key:value object from a flat object

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-6

**I'm using Javascript to get data from an API.**
I get the following list of objects.

```
[
    {name: 'Cat', value: 2, extra: 'data'},
    {name: 'Dog', value: 3, extra: 'data'}
]
```

I'm trying to get to the following form

```
[
    cat: {value: 2},
    dog: {value: 3}
]
```

### I'm currently trying using map but I don't see where the key part comes in.

```
return data.map((item) => ({
    value: item.value
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [
    {name: 'Cat', value1: 2, value2: 3},
    {name: 'Dog', value1: 3, value2: 4}
]

var result = data.map((item) => {
    var name = item.name
    delete item.name
    //if you want to modify some property
    item.value1 = item.value1 + "$"
    return {[name]: {...item}}
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I did like your previous answer better, I can't add a string to one of the properties for example, if I want to add a $ sign behind the 2 value for cat.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this version would be more generic.

Comment: Is it still possible to modify certain parameters using this version?

Answer (score 2):

```
const result = {};
for(const {name, value} of array)
 result[name] = { value };
```

A plain old for loop does it. With functional programming you would have to use `reduce` to boil it down to *one single object*, `map` always returns an array.

```
const result = array.reduce((res, {name, value}) => ({ ...res, [name]: {value}}), {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the last line is giving a syntax error .

Comment: @notflip oops, missed a bracket :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()` with `map()` method to return object as a result.

```js
const data = [{name: 'Cat', value: 2},{name: 'Dog', value: 3}]

const result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({name, value}) => ({[name]: {value}})))
console.log(result)
```